# Edit excel file with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I tried to edit an existing excel file. My file is `test.xlsx`, with two sheets are `All` and `Summary`. Following step:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv') 
 number_rows = len(df.index) 
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx') 
 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'All',startrow = number_rows) 
 writer.save()
```

I want to edit(append data to sheet name `All`) but when run this code, it seem to be the sheet name `Summary` and `All` deleted and it create a new sheet name `All` and write my new data to it. So, how to append data to excel sheet without delete existing data? Thank you.

Comment: You need to read your excel data in first. All you're doing is blowing away your existing excel file with an entirely new one. This is covered by the panda docs of these calls.

Comment: @pvg the same result if i am not read dataframe from csv, read dataframe from excel file itself ` df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')` replace line 2

Comment: You should read the docs and/or google for some examples of this, it's not going to work if you randomly change the code in the hopes it magically works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) engine along-with startrow parameter. 
You also need to ;

- read csv to df first
- open xlsx as workbook using `openpyxl`
- create writer object using `openpyxl` as engine
- Add sheets to writer object
- Add df to writer object

Your Code (modified):

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
number_rows = len(df.index) 
book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'All',startrow = number_rows) 
writer.save()
```