# Is there any way to view `dataframe` in Excel without save?

Tags: pandas, excel

Is there any way to view `dataframe` in Excel without save?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3], 'b': [10,20,30]})
df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']
df['d'] = 'test'
df2 = df.sort_values('a', ascending = False)


# I want to see 'df2' in excel without save process(i.e. 'to_csv').
```

Currently, in the spyder IDE I'm using, I open the `dataframe` through 'variable explorer' and then copy and paste all cells into an empty Excel sheet.

Comment: + 'Excel' tag? Also csv is no obligation. Don't forget [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Are you looking to edit an existing file? Then use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/43083111/12846804

Comment: I mean new DataFrame. I want to see this DataFrame via Excel.

Comment: Oh so you would like an Excel window to pop up with the dataframe in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you're talking about running Excel as a supporting program, then [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/index.html) is a good choice. Here's a minimal workflow to get the gist of it:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

# Create a new book in a separate Excel instance 
# and get its first worksheet
wb = xw.Book()
ws = wb.sheets[0]

# Prepare data to display in Excel
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': range(10),
    'B': range(10,20)
})

# Write the data starting on the very first cell
ws['a1'].value = df

# Close the workbook without saving
wb.close()
```

Here's how it looks side by side with Jupyter Notebook:

[image: screenshot jupyter and excel]

Excel was opened and controlled solely by code in the notebook. When `wb.close()` is executed, the Excel window will be closed without saving.

- [xlwings quick start](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html)
- [interacting with Excel from Jupyter Notebook](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/jupyternotebooks.html#jupyternotebooks)
- [xlwings installation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html#installation)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`to_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html):

```
df2.to_clipboard()
```

You can now paste (Ctrl+V) your data into an excel sheet.